# Comparing lists identity with templates

Tags: c#

I'm curious why this code generate compilation error "cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'are_lists_equal(List, List)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'test_t' to 'System.IComparable". Whereas class test_t obviously supports ICompatible interface.

```
    public class test_t             : IComparable<test_t> {
        public int                  CompareTo                           ( test_t o ){ return 0; }
        public static bool          compare                             ( List<test_t> a, List<test_t> b ){
            return                  are_lists_equal<test_t>             ( a, b );
        }
    }

    public static bool              are_lists_equal<T>                  ( List<T> a, List<T> b ) where T:IComparable{
        if( a==null && b==null )    return true;
        if( a==null || b==null )    return false;
        if( a.Count!=b.Count )      return false;
        for( int i=0; i<a.Count; i++ ){
            if( a[i].CompareTo(b[i])!=0 )   return false;
        }
        return  true;
    }
```

Thanks !

Comment: Forget about vis_base_t. Same error occurs with test_t. You can easy replicate.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `where` statement on the method `are_lists_equal` from `where T : IComparable` to `where T : IComparable<T>`.

`IComparable` really is a *different type* than `IComparable<T>`, which is what the compiler is complaining about.  (You can go to definition or else F1 help on both `IComparable` and `IComparable<T>` to see this.)